# How can I calculate the flow rate necessary for a given cross sectional area, angle, and length

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics

[image]

I'm making a toy for my kids and this problem came up. I have a channel on a slight angle (angle is between ground and length of channel) and I'm pouring water into it. I want to know how quickly I need to pour water in to make it flow continuously at a given height.

So the water is (meant to be) .5m wide, .2m high, and 1m long, angled at 5 degrees. How fast is that water going to fall out, in other words, how fast do I have to pour it in?

I'm particularly looking for the technique to do this, not just an answer.

The part I find very confusing is that the water at the top of the box will accelerate a little, and have a low velocity, while the water at the bottom of the box will have accelerated for a while, and have a higher velocity. But intuition tells me the water will stay cohesive, for lack of a better word. Can someone explain what's going on here and how this can be calculated?

Comment: The situation is completely unclear. Is the box full? What do you mean flow continuously?

Comment: Also you need to state the angle of inclination more clearly. 5 degrees with respect to what?

Comment: @RonMaimon - I appreciate your help, but 'completely unclear?' I stated the volume of water and cross sectional area of water (well, indirectly, with all dimensions), the point is gravity is going to remove this water at a certain rate and I need to replenish it at the same rate. I showed this question to an engineer and he said 'open channel flow rate, mannings equation'.

Comment: @upapilot 5 degrees with respect to the surface of the Earth.

Comment: @Henry: What's unclear: What's the channel? Is the water filling up the box then falling out the lower height wall? What is "flow continuously"? What is the alternative to "flowing continuously"? At any flow rate you put in, the water gets into the box and falls out the low side. As much water as you put in, that's the water that goes out, and it's always continuous at any rate (if you ignore surface tension effects). Are you interested in drip-drip flow? In gushing turbulent flow? In laminar intermediate flow? It's not clear at all what you are asking.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30052/how-much-water-must-flow-trough-canal-to-maintain-a-constant-water-deep

Comment: Thanks for the diagram--- I changed the downvote to an upvote. I can tell you why I was confused--- when you said "box", a box has four walls, and you have a box which is not a box, but a channel. I imagined that the water was piling up on the lower wall, and dribbling over the top. The question now has a clear answer--- the height of the water diminishes with distance, as the water speeds up, so that the depth of the water at the lower end is less than at the high end.

Answer (score 1):

I was told by an engineer to use Manning's equation for open channel flow rate, as described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manning_formula

Manning coefficient for some common materials: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/mannings-roughness-d_799.html - in my case it was acrylic sheet so 0.009 worked fine

Combining with discharge as stated in the wikipedia article means you can avoid calculating the velocity if you don't need it.

Q = cubic meters per second

A = .2 * .5 (cross sectional area in meters squared)

Rh = A / P, P is the wetted perimeter in this case .2 + .2 + .5

S = 0.09 (tan(5 degrees))

k = m^1/3/s

n = 0.009

So 0.08m^3/s, or in liters, 80 liters/second

Hmm, not sure if that is actually correct, but it's the right approach, and if correct, tells me I need to decrease the angle and decrease the depth in order to achieve a flow rate that I can find a cheap pump for!

Comment: How is this an answer? The amount that flows out depends on how much flows in--- if you put more in, more comes out.

Comment: @RonMaimon well, if you put more in, the cross sectional area increases, and if you put less in, it decreases. So if you put more in, yes more comes out, but it's no longer the same open channel situation (eg, you are overflowing the channel). This gives me the 'correct' amount to put in and take out (they are equal) to achieve this particular channel configuration. Does that make sense?

Comment: What are you talking about!! It is impossible to understand you. I am voting to close and -1 on this answer.

Comment: What is the "channel"? Why does the cross sectional area increase? You are _always_ overflowing the channel when stuff comes out. Please draw a picture or link a movie--- I don't think you are describing something real.

Comment: Please refer to this article for a drawing and some discussion: http://tiny.cc/9pr7gw In the context of my question and answer, imagine the channel is 3y tall, and I am *aiming* for a cross sectional area of water y tall. In other words I am *controlling* the flow rate in order to achieve a given area and hydraulic radius. To determine the correct flow rate, I use the manning equation and solve for Q, giving me a value to search out a pump. Also, please relax :)

Comment: @RonMaimon I added a diagram, I hope it helps. I wonder if perhaps an engineering type stack exchange would be more appropriate for this discussion...

Comment: No, this is a fine question, the problem was that the description didn't give the geometry in a clear way, and I was frustrated by not seeing the picture (I looked at it for a while). The channel flow is not at a constant velocity in this case, the water accelerates as it goes down the ramp (the viscosity is not enough to make a steady state) so the water height is just not constant as you go down the ramp. You can find the water depth as a function of distance along the ramp using conservation of fluid and conservation of energy, assuming no friction. I'll remove downvote from your answer.

Comment: @RonMaimon Thank you, and I have fixed the text as well (while leaving the question's ignorance largely the same). I will try to clean up my future questions before I post next time, sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a frictional force between the water flowing in the channel and the sides of the channel. This force slows the water down. If you wish to have the height of the water stay constant through the channel you will have to balance this force with that of gravity. This frictional force will depend on the velocity of the water; the faster the water the higher the frictional force.

To estimate the frictional force, look for equations that give the decrease in "head" in water due to flowing through the pipe. That is, if you apply a certain pressure to a long open pipe, you will get a certain flow. If you make the pipe longer, the flow will decrease. Since the pressure on the exit end of the pipe is zero, you can compute how much work was done on the water (in moving it from a pressure P to a pressure of 0). The work done on the water this way is equal to the frictional work = force x distance, and so you can calculate the friction.

Since you can adjust the gravitational force by changing the angle of tilt of the channel, you can rest assured that for any (reasonable) velocity, you can balance the frictional force with the gravitational force. By "reasonable" I mean that you can't make the water fall faster than gravity with no friction. And you channel needs to have a region towards the top where either (1) the water is slower and so the channel is higher, or (2) the water has an initial non-zero velocity because, for example, a pressure.

I think this should be enough to get you started on this problem. If you have further questions, put them in the comments and someone will probably work on it further.